# Magento unable to add a product to a category

Tags: magento

Whenever I try to add a product to a category I get this error.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db2018`.`catalog_category_product`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_oud` (`entity_id`) ON DE), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product` (`category_id`,`product_id`,`position`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)

Seems like there are no values being submitted?

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this fixed?

Comment: Still have the problem, here is a post with a possible repair strategy for a "corrupt" database. https://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase/70/Error---SQLSTATE23000-Integrity-constraint-violation-1452-Cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails-databasenamemagentocatalogcategoryproductindex-CONSTRAINT-FKCATCTGRPRDIDXCTGRIDCATCTGRENTTENTTID-FOREIGN-KEY-categoryid-REFERENCES-catalogcategoryentity-entity.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?